# How to fix 'No tests were executed! (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)' error with -Dtest flag

Tags: java, maven, automation

I am trying to run a singular (or short list of tests) from the command line with the Dtest flag, like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\Installed_Automatically\bin\mvn" -B -T 10 -fn -f "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Nightly\qaauto\pom.xml" clean test -PNightly1 -Dtest=testcases.TestCaseA
```

But when I run the call I get the error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) on project Automation: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
```

If I run the command line without '-Dtest=testcases.TestCaseA', it runs all tests that are defined in the 'Nightly1' profile, including the 'TestCaseA'.

I am not sure if this is due to the fact that our directories are in no way standard - such as instead of our test sources being in 'src/test/java' they are in 'src/testcases' but then I am confused as to why it works just fine without the -Dtest flag.

Below is an example of what is in our TestNG config 'Nightly1':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Nightly1" parallel="tests" thread-count="10" preserve-order="false">
    <parameter name="sauceOs" value="win7" />
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="sauceBrowserVersion" value=""/>
    <parameter name="remoteOrLocal" value="remote" />
    <parameter name="maxDurationForSauce" value="10800"></parameter>
    <parameter name="environment" value="stage" />
    <parameter name="remoteAddress" value="1.1.1.1" />
    <parameter name="throttle" value="250" />
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="utilities.RetryListener"/>
    <!--<listener class-name = "utilities.CaptureScreenshot" />-->
    </listeners>
    <test name="TestCase">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="TestCase"></include>
                <exclude name="stupidLong"></exclude>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="testcases"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And an example of our POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Automation</groupId>
    <artifactId>Automation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Automation</name>

    <properties>
        <!--<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding> -->
        <maven.compiler.version>3.7.0</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.surefire.plugin.version>3.0.0-M3</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <profiles>
....
        <profile>
            <id>Nightly1</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Xms1g</argLine>
                            <argLine>-Xmx2g</argLine>
                            <argLine>-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError</argLine>
                            <argLine>-XX:HeapDumpPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\JavaHeapdumps"</argLine>
                            <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                            <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>Nightly1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
...
```

Comment: First I would suggest to follow convention over configuration and locate your code incl. test into src/main/java code and tests into src/test/java and remove the sourceDirectory and recources configuration..

Comment: @khmarbaise Tried that and got the error:

`[ERROR] initialize(testcases.TestCaseA)  Time elapsed: 0.329 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.testng.TestNGException:

Parameter 'browser' is required by @Configuration on method initialize but has not been marked @Optional or defined`

Comment: Your tests are broken...